# FILE * streams with dup2()-ed descriptors — stdin not working

Tags: c, linux, pipe

After forking a child and dub2()-ing its stdin descriptor to the read-end of a pipe (its write-end is in the parent process) reading with read(0,...) (descriptor based) works fine. But reading with fgets(stdin,...) (stream based) does not work. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char string[]="MY TEST STRING";
    pid_t pid;
    int bufSize=80;
    char rBuf[bufSize];
    int downlink[2], wrlen=0, rdlen=0, status;
    memset(rBuf,0,bufSize);

    if (pipe (downlink) == -1){
        printf("Error with pipe()\n");
        exit(4);
    }

    pid=fork();
    if (pid>0){              //parent

        wrlen=wrlen+write(downlink[1], string, strlen(string)+1);
        //dprintf(downlink[1],"%s", string);
        sleep(6);

    }
    else if (pid == 0){      // child

        dup2(downlink[0],STDIN_FILENO);

        //rdlen=read(downlink[0], rBuf, bufSize);          //works
        //rdlen=read(STDIN_FILENO, rBuf, bufSize);           //works        
        //scanf("%s", rBuf);fflush(stdin);                 //doesn't work, reads up to first blank
        //scanf(stdin,"%s", rBuf);fflush(stdin);           //doesn't work, reads up to first blank
        fgets(rBuf, bufSize, stdin);fflush(stdin);       //doesn't work
        printf("c: %s", rBuf), fflush(stdout);
        //status =execl("/usr/bin/octave","octave","--no-gui",NULL);
        //status =execl("/usr/bin/man","man",NULL);

        //printf("c: status%d", status), fflush(stdout);

    }
    else{                    //error
        printf("Error with fork()\n");
        exit(4);
    }
return 0;
}
```

In this code the fork()ed child is supposed to read from stdin (which is dub2()ed to downlink[0](=read-end of pipe from writing parent)) and printf() to stdout the received contets.
If the reading happens with read() (descriptor based) everything works fine. When reading with fgets() or scanf() (stream based) no data is printed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Show the code that writes the newline that marks the end of the line to `fgets()`.  Using `read()`, line boundaries and null bytes are not an issue; using `fgets()`, both newlines and null bytes are an issue.  Also show the code that's doing the reading, too.  And did you remember to close the write end of the pipe in the child process?  The child won't get EOF unless you close the child's copy of the write end of the pipe before you try reading.

Comment: Sorry Sir, you were so quick when commenting that I even have not finished editing my question. Now the code is there and a bit more specifics...

Comment: Please don't post incomplete questions — finish your editing before wasting our time looking at incomplete questions.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: It looks like my original comment covered most of the problems.  You should also close the pipe file descriptors in the parent before sleeping.  You are writing the null byte at the end of the string to the pipe.  There's no problem with that except you can't reliably use `fgets()`.  If you wrote several messages and had a newline before the null byte in each message, and if the child looped to read information until EOF, its second input would be truncated by the null byte.  Be cautious.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` reads a line, but your parent process never sends a line of text. So you need to add a newline to your `string`

```
 char string[]="MY TEST STRING\n";
```

`read()` however just reads whatever is in the pipe when it becomes available - it does not try to read all the data it can up till a newline character, which is why you get data back when using `read()`

Even when you do not send a newline, `fgets()` would return when the write end of the pipe gets closed. However the pipe you create in your parent process gets copied into the child process.

That means that when the parent process exits, its write end of the pipe is closed - but not the write end of the pipe in the child process - leading to the pipe still being open when the parent exit.

So make sure you close() the write end of the pipe in your child process, as you don't need it:

```
else if (pid == 0){      // child
        close(downlink[1]);
        dup2(downlink[0],STDIN_FILENO);
```

Comment: Also close the read end of the pipe in the child after using `dup2()` to connect it to `stdin`.  Also close the read end of the pipe in the parent, unconditionally.  And close the write end of the pipe in the parent when all the messages have been sent (probably before sleeping).

Comment: @nos the hint about the missing '\n' did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I know that I should close them. (Left that out here to reduce clutter...) It seems to work without closing them though. I'm wondering just out of curiosity what happens if they stay open without being used.

Comment: @K.Nick — It depends.  See my comment to the main question.  While the child simply reads one line, there's not much that goes wrong.  However, as soon as the child tries to read to EOF, you have an indefinite wait.  It's good that you know you need to close the pipes.  However, for the correct operation of many (most?) programs, it is important to actually close the pipes — the correct functioning of the code depends on that and not closing them yields problems (typically, processes hung in a `read()` system call; occasionally stuck in a `write()` call).